# Get filenames if string in xml-file is matched

Tags: xml, xquery

I`m trying to get the filenames (including the path) of xml-files that contain a specific string.

```
for $file in doc("allfiles.xml")/allfiles/doc,
    $thefile in doc(concat("../data/", $file/@href)),
    $profile in $here/there/header/profile[contains(., "thespecificstring")]
return
    $getfilename
```

The for-statement works, but what do I need to put in the return? I just don't unterstand the documentation.

Comment: Please share your XML file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your input and desired output, it's hard to tell, but perhaps you want `document-uri($thefile)`.

Comment: It was that easy, many thanks! Works as expected. (What an honor to get help from you!)